# jquery/html/ajax - jquery not showing/hiding elements

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to make a spy phone (pls dont ask) using html, jquery, and css
the css isn't the problem
its more of the jquery

```
    <div id="spyphone" class="spyphone">
            <button id="messagebutton"class="spyphonebutton">Messages</button>
            <div id="messages">
                <p>hai</p>
            </div>
            <button class="spyphonebutton">Browser</button>
            <iframe id="browser" src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
            <button id="exit">Exit</button>
            <script>
                $("#messages").hide();
                $("#browser").hide();
                $("#exit").hide();
                $("#messagebutton").click(function () { 
                    $("#exit").show(); 
                    $("#messages").show();
                });
                $("#exit").click(function () { 
                    if ($("#messages:visible") == true) {
                        $("#messages").hide(); // does not hide the messages
                        $("#exit").hide(); // does not hide exit button
                    } else if ($("#browser:visible") == true) {
                        $("#browser").hide();
                    }
                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End of spy phone -->
```

This is very strange problem. No output...
It should work but it doesn't... I have no other information about it....

Comment: And also, I should note that the browser does not work when I show the iframe. (not with the button as there is no event handler for it, but with the command line)

Comment: Try another website. I don't believe you can load google.com into an iframe. I could be wrong though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("#messages:visible")` returns jQuery object , not `Boolean` .

Try utilizing `.is()` , substituting `$("#messages").is(":visible")` for `$("#messages:visible") == true`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="spyphone" class="spyphone">
            <button id="messagebutton"class="spyphonebutton">Messages</button>
            <div id="messages">
                <p>hai</p>
            </div>
            <button class="spyphonebutton">Browser</button>
            <iframe id="browser" src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
            <button id="exit">Exit</button>
            <script>
                $("#messages").hide();
                console.log($("#messages:visible")
                            , $("#messages:visible") === false);
                $("#browser").hide();
                $("#exit").hide();
                $("#messagebutton").click(function () { 
                    $("#exit").show(); 
                    $("#messages").show();
                });
                $("#exit").click(function () { 
                    if ($("#messages").is(":visible")) {
                        $("#messages").hide(); // does not hide the messages
                        $("#exit").hide(); // does not hide exit button
                    } else if (!$("#browser").is(":visible")) {
                        $("#browser").hide();
                    }
                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
```